# What is the correct XPath syntax to get an element's value using the value of another element at the same level?

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing, xmllint

Given the below XML, what is the correct XPath expression to extract the id value for a given name value?

(eg: I want xmllint to return an id value of "someID" when given a name value of "someName")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <record>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <id>someID</id>
                <name>someName</name>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <id>someOtherID</id>
                <name>someOtherName</name>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </records>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the *sibling* axis.

```
xmllint --xpath '//name[.="someName"]/preceding-sibling::id/text()' file.xml
```

Or, you can go up to the `attribute` and back down to `id`:

```
'//name[.="someName"]/../id/text()'
```

Answer (score 0):

> what is the correct XPath expression

There's no single correct answer. There are lots of ways to select the `id` based on the sibling `name`.

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59747224/317052) (there's only one right now) shows two ways. Here are two more...

```
xmllint --xpath '//id[../name="someName"]/text()' input_file.xml
```

and

```
xmllint --xpath '//attribute[name="someName"]/id/text()' input_file.xml
```